# Regex getting only all first consecutive match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/s3fdjyjv/1

```
var re = /11\B/g; 
var str = '11111vjknvkjdnfvk11kjdnkjfgbnkfgjbnk1111jkngknfbkjf11111111gbnf';

console.log(str.match(re));
```

I am trying to get only the first set of consecutive matches.

So, in this example I just want to get the first consecutive matches of  `11`, which should result in the first `1111`.

How can I get this result?

Comment: Just `/(11)\1+/` should be enough. See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pwc5f1sr/)

Comment: regexr.com is awesome for this stuff. btw

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! How can I do that on a `new RegExp()` format?

Comment: Like this: `var re = new RegExp("(11)\\1+");`, but you do not need this since the pattern is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/11\B/g` regex matches multiple `11` substrings that are followed with an alphanumeric character or an underscore, as `\B` is a *non-word boundary*.

> I am trying to get only the first set of consecutive matches.

For that, you need a *capturing group* and a *backreference*:

```
var re = /(11)\1+/;
```

or
    var re = new RegExp("(11)\1+");

Note the `/g` global modifier must be removed since you only need the first match.

```js
var re = new RegExp("(11)\\1+"); 
var str = '11111vjknvkjdnfvk11kjdnkjfgbnkfgjbnk1111jkngknfbkjf11111111gbnf';
var m = str.match(re);
var res = m ? m[0] + ", at " + re.lastIndex : "";
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If you found my answer helpful please also consider upvoting.